# how to filter control character in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

like

```
JSON.parse('{"text": "~#"}');
```

will give synatax error, because there is 0x0B between ~ and #. you can't see it, but it does exists.

How to avoid that?

Comment: Encode those characters as per the JSON spec.

Comment: @alex I can't control the server response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't get the data encoded on the server, then one way is to pre-process it into JSON before attempting a decode. You might for example, apply a RegExp like so:

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"text":   "~#"}'.replace(/([^\d\w"':,{}~#]|\s)+/g, ' '));
```

Obviosly, you want to follow the [spec](http://www.json.org/) really closely when crafting the RegExp.

Comment: Edited to make the Expression allow whitespace. However, this'll add possibly unwanted space.